# Latitude D600 USB port

Tags: usb, dell-latitude

Both USB ports stopped communicating on my D600, they have power, my optical mouse still lights up, no device works on the ports, and everything is fine in Device Manager in Dual boot Windows XP and Windows 7. I checked the BIOS, not much in there for USB.

No USB device shows up when I use the F12/ boot device menu either, so it must be some hardware issue.

I have another hard drive with Ubuntu on it, popped it in, and USB does not communicate with it either.

It appears to have 5 V, but no communication. Any ideas besides another motherboard or USB card for the PCMCIA slot (these don't work to well from my research)?

I mostly use them for mass storage devices and PCMCIA slots don't supply enough power for these devices.

Thanks to all who answer with last ditch efforts. I hate to give up on it. It's been good to me and still runs rather well for its vintage.

I did inspect the ports with a flashlight and did a partial disassembly of the laptop in an attempt to check the solder joints, but it would require complete motherboard removal to see them, that is where I stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the range of systems you say can't see it. I would also suspect a problem in the port itself.  Because it seems that you can get these for under $10 on Ebay
search for "dell d600 usb board"
I think I might be tempted to give one of them a try.

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/latd600/sm/index.htm

Comment: Thanks, I have never had a usb port become defective, but I guess it could be a first in 15 years, I did inspect it with a flashlight and did a partial disassembly of the laptop in an attempt to check the solder joints, but would require complete motherboard removal to see them, that is where I stopped.

Comment: Damn, it is separate from the motherboard, thanks again! Ordering one now!

Comment: Because I have several of these I'll be interested to follow this for future reference. That thing sure looks like it just connects via a cable though.    (posted before your comment refreshed) Good luck

Comment: At least I have hope now, just ordered a used one from eBay, $3.69 free ship! Thanks again Dennis, I will give it a little time then accept your solution.

Comment: OMG, I read your bio, I am from Ohio originally, Columbus, then Dayton, moved to Texas in 76, don't miss the weather. Nice M.A.N. website!

Comment: Installed the new/used usb board, no change, I guess its the motherboard, BTW it requires complete disassembly of the laptop to replace that board. I can't believe what people want for motherboards for this model, considering the value of one in working order.